# meaning of the word "Engagement"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

whats the meaning of Engagements in this phrase?

While I enjoyed and benefited from working with many other services, notably those of the Russian and Chinese, it was during my many years living and traveling in the Middle East and South Asia that I had the most intriguing and captivating **engagements**.

Comment: It would help to know who 'I' is, and what 'services' they worked for.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the four possibilities in [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/engagement), it can be deduced that "1" is out of the question, and as well  "4" does not correspond to the situation. "3" is then could be the meaning that is proper.

> mass noun The action of engaging or being engaged.
> ‘Britain's continued engagement in open trading’
> synonyms : participation, participating, taking part, sharing, partaking, involvement, association

Looking up "*engage*" in [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/engage), sense "2" could be seen to be the proper meaning of "engage" in the preceding definition.

> engage in or be engaged in (no object) Participate or become involved in.
> ‘organizations engage in a variety of activities’

A synonym of "engagement" would therefore be "*involvement*".

- While I enjoyed and benefited from working with many other services, notably those of the Russian and Chinese, it was during my many years living and traveling in the Middle East and South Asia that I had the most intriguing and captivating **involvements**.

However, since the author appears to be a journalist working for various services, the professional term is more likely to be the correct one, that is choice "2" is proper. (see **user Dan**'s comment in comment section)

> ([lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/engagement)) An arrangement to do something or go somewhere at a fixed time.
> ‘a dinner engagement’
> synonyms : appointment, arrangement, commitment, meeting, tweetup, interview, consultation, session

A synonym could be "arrangement" or even "interview" if these arrangements are nothing else but interviews. However, "arrangements" does not seem to be an idiomatic synonym, only "interview" is.

- <sup>?</sup>While I enjoyed and benefited from working with many other services, notably those of the Russian and Chinese, it was during my many years living and traveling in the Middle East and South Asia that I had the most intriguing and captivating **arrangements**.

Comment: From your first [lexico link](https://www.lexico.com/definition/engagement), I would choose  "2. An arrangement to do something or go somewhere at a fixed time". One of the example sentences is: "Then we have about 30 engagements a year, which can involve a lot of travelling."

Comment: @Dan I suppose that since the matter is working for a service, most probably as a journalist, it is most likely that choice "2" is the right one. I will allow for that.